# Hook that fires any time ANY file is opened?

Tags: init-file, hooks

Is there a hook that gets called any time a file is opened, not a buffer but an actual file?

Answer (score 6):

```
find-file-hook
```

Documentation:
List of functions to be called after a buffer is loaded from a file.
The buffer’s local variables (if any) will have been processed before the
functions are called.

Comment: I was trying this, and I could be mistaken but this doesn't seem to fire if I use something other than find-file to open the file.